# USB stick read-only in GNOME/nautilus?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, usb-drive, nautilus, readonly

Funnily, my newly vfat-formatted USB stick is automatically mounted when I plug it in, nautilus sees it, I can access it, I can see the permissions in the nautilus right click dialog (755), I can create and delete files from command line:

```
$ touch/run/mount/christian/XXXX-XXXX/anyfile.txt
```

I can even move files (with Del key) into trash from within nautilus.

But when I try to create a new directory,a new file, or copy a file to that stick **using nautilus** in Arch linux, I just get the error message (German):

```
Fehler beim Kopieren nach »Datenträger 4,0 GB«.
Das Ziel ist schreibgeschützt
```

Which means: **Error copying to »Storage device 4,0 GB - Target is read-only«

I don't get it. It can't be on OS layer. I can touch, delete, renamy, copy anything on the command line. It must be something GNOME restricts. Is it necessary to be in a group in Arch/GNOME to write to USB devices? And why can I delete files (Move to trash **and** delete is possible from within nautilus!)
I am in the following groups:

```
sys lp wheel network video audio storage power libvirt users
```

Comment: "schreibgeschützt" doesn't mean read-only, it means write-protected, and that is something entirely different. E.g. a CD-ROM is **not** write-protected, but it is read-Only

Comment: What's the difference b'tween read-only and write-protected in practice? What can I do on a CD-ROM, other than reading?

Comment: Hm. I today checked again, and everything works as intended. I did not change anything. The only thing that could explain it, I made updates in between, and they could have produced some weird behaviour, maybe by updating a component that had influence on the mounting process. and I did not reboot then. Today, after a fresh start, this problem is gone. Can I mark this question as invalid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it is related with this nautilus bug [Nautilus says the USB stick is read only when it is not](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1021375). Restarting nautilus clears the issue (at least temporally):

```
$ killall nautilus
```

Comment: Maybe that is the problem. Could not reproduce it reliably.